# Regex that matches the following character

Tags: regex

Regex that matches following patterns

```
1. mrrtjjsf8907m5q29ui
2. 0?userid=y1arx6uxb1nidmz3tguv
3. bryj9itvwjmbyv3wg8ef
```

I am trying to pass these values to another variable `col=?([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})`

it is taking the right values for first and three for second one it is taking values 0

instead it should take `y1arx6uxb1nidmz3tguv`

Comment: I think you need to tell more about the pattern and why it is matching these three examples.

Comment: I assume you want to replace `col=?` with something like `(?:\d+\?[^=]+=)?` -- "match zero or more of some digits followd by a question mark followed by some note-equals-signs followd by an equal-sign" -- but without an explanation what the pattern is you're trying to match, it's hard to tell

Comment: @satheesh since you are not considering `0` as a valid match thus it indirectly reveals that you want bunch of characters that contains both numbers and alphabets isn't it ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the last 1 to 20 alphanum chars? Then use [`[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}$`](https://regex101.com/r/rmTQGI/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this regex instead:

```
[a-zA-Z](?=[A-Za-z]*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,19}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gMIcAA/7)

This will make sure that the bunch of characters that you are going to match is only built of alphabets and numeber thus `0` Or `userid` are not considered as match!

**Alternative:**

But the above may not consider the case where a valid sequence may start with number instead of alphabet. In that case you may use the following regex which will consider both situation:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z](?=[A-Za-z]*\d)|\d(?=\d*[A-Za-z]))[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,19}
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gMIcAA/9/)

Comment: Thanks the second one is matching however i could not pass the value when i was using this before  col=?([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}) it passed mrrtjjsf8907m5q29ui, 0, bryj9itvwjmbyv3wg8ef

Comment: You didn't even mentioned the language , or any code snippet where you tried to pass the value... you need to do something about it .. if you want better answers

Comment: Thanks for helping a lot just type this col=?([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}) and type 1. mrrtjjsf8907m5q29ui
2. 0?userid=y1arx6uxb1nidmz3tguv
3. bryj9itvwjmbyv3wg8ef

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not wanting to match anything before an equal sign `=`. You can use the line terminator `$` to ensure that it will match your your characters and stop at any non-matching characters.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})$
```

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uaQbga/2)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` does not match `=`, why are you trying to restrict the first char matched with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` then? You must have been thinking about a lookbehind, `(?<!=)`.

Comment: You are correct. The lookahead is redundant as you've stated. I appreciate the feedback.